# Bootstrap - Position 1 item to the left while preserving another item's center position

Tags: html, css, positioning

I cannot think of a way to have the logo on the left of the navbar but for the items to be perfectly centered. I tried using margin auto for the items but then they move further right away from the center because of the logo taking up space.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center d-flex">
    <a class="navbar-brand">WIDE-LOGO-TEXT</a>

    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Second NavBar: --> 

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex">
    <a class="navbar-brand">WIDE-LOGO-TEXT</a>

    <ul class="navbar-nav" style="margin: 0 auto;">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/DUmlhXetYE

As you can see from the preview link above, the 2nd navbar items are in the exact same position at the first navbar items. The problem is that I want these to be perfectly centered as though the logo was never there. Therefore I need the nav items to shift to the left to be perfectly centered and unaffected by the logo.

How can I do this? Hope that makes sense!

EDIT: Image to illustrate issue more clearly:

[image]

Comment: You want to shift the 2nd navbar items to the left. Is that it? The description and the question title are not relating. So use image editor tool to describe your situation please.

Comment: @ManojKumar I want the logo to be on the left without affecting the navbar items (home, gallery, etc...). So those items need to be positioned in the very center of the navbar but as you can see from the preview they are not centered because they are further right because of the logo taking up space. I don't see a problem with the title. I'm using the bootstrap navbar components.

Comment: @ManojKumar I've added an image to illustrate the problem

Comment: Ok I got to know about the problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 way to fix your problem.

**1)** Logo class apply css `position: absolute` and parent class apply css `position: relative;`

**2)** Menu Class `navbar-nav` apply css `transform: translateX(-80px);` you can get navigation center align. as per your expectation.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if there was a way of using flex to do this because it's an area I'm less familiar with. Using position absolute makes sense though. I don't like the idea of hacking around things by relying on pixel shifting (logo could change width in the future etc...)

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute positioning:

```
.navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    left: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use Bootstrap 4 for this kind of predefined library of css.
Copy paste the below code you found the result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTuhs.png)

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

```html
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
    <button class="navbar-toggler mr-2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <span class="navbar-brand d-flex flex-fill">WIDE-LOGO-TEXT</span>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-center d-flex flex-fill">
             <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link">Gallery</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-fill"><!--spacer--> </div>
</nav>


<div class="container-fluid">
    <h5 class="text-center">--center--</h5>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Best of luck :)

Comment: Thanks. I prefer using bootstrap too if possible. The menu items need to be centered on the page without the influence of the logo moving it to the right. Your code and image show it doesn't center the menu items but thanks for the bootstrap advice.